# Creating entity for database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

For example, I have database with table book (id, title, themeId, authorId), table author (id, name) and table theme (id, name). I dont know, should i create entity exactly like in database (and then i will have problems with join queries):

```
class Book {
    private id;
    String title;
    int bookThemeId;
    int bookAuthorId;
}
```

or create something like this:

```
class Book {
    private id;
    String title;
    BookTheme bookTheme;
    Author bookAuthor;
}
```

in second case i will have problems if authorId or themeId is null (it may be) and problems with getting from DAO in general, if i want get only books list (problems - fields is null, and very bulky builder for Book entity).

Comment: Second option would preclude books with multiple themes and authors.

Comment: @P.Salmon its not a big deal for this moment, its just example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the second option because is more object oriented. If you go with the first option, you will need to do a second query to get the details.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    //... 

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "theme_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private BookTheme bookTheme;

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

Your id will be null when fields are not created, right?
For instance, when it is saved on database, it will always have an id.

Comment: Thank you for answer, yes i like second option too, but i dont use annotation and JPA for the time being learn servlets so i dont understand what exactly you mean by using annotations. About ids - i mean foreign id, like themeId, it may be null, so we can catch NullPointerException while using entities from second option.

Comment: I would not catch NullPointException instead just check if a variable if null or not. It is cleaner.

Comment: Ok, i think null-checking low price for easy entity using

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go with 2nd approach. There will be no issue if your BookTheme r Author will be null if you use `optional=true`. For bulky builder, you can use `fetchtype as lazy`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "theme_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private BookTheme bookTheme;

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

Hope, This will work!

Comment: Thank you for answer, i get you, but i dont use annotations and JPA.

Comment: If you are not using that thn you should go with 1st approach

Comment: Why should i go with 1st option, if i dont use annotation?

Comment: If you go with 2nd option thn it will be bulky. In first option if you use primitive thn u can handle null thing and also get only id rather thn whole object.